# How to make effect of burning objects from Particles?

Tags: modifiers, particles

How to make so that Boolean affect on color & shape of particles?

Here's example, I need to create effect so that grass from Particles burns. But grass doesn't change color & shape from Boolean & Dynamic paint like ground does. Particles just disappear when circle narrows.

I guess that for particles need to use not Dynamic paint, but something else. The only thing that comes to my mind is converting particles to mesh, but this is inconvenient variant, especially when particles are animated.

How to make so that Boolean affect on color & shape of particles? Or maybe not Boolean, but something else. In general, how to make effect of burning particles (on the example of burning grass or something similar)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an easy solution in the direction your heading.
And probaply no easy solutions exists.

But know that Blender understands Python, and with that it should be possible.
If you know the locations of the object replace them, or better use shape keys on them to shrink them. Then be able to move a texture over the object so it turns black from top to bottom. Doing this with python might not be easy, though all actions you do are logged inside

Maybe animation nodes could allow something like this (but i'm not sure).
Generating trees with leaves is one of the goals though.

Comment: Oh no, I don't know how to use Python & Animation nodes. OK, thanks for answer, I'll try to find some alternative.